# How can I remove phrases starting with 'no' and their respective commas from a comma separated list, leaving the rest?

Tags: php

How can I remove anything with 'no' and their respective commas from $elements, leaving the rest?

```
$elements = "cheese, no tomato, no onion, mayo, no lettuce";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to solve this is to split the list of ingredients on a comma, then filter out the values which start with `no` then implode the list again. This has the advantage of not leaving hanging commas in the output:

```
function filter_ingredients($elements) {
    return implode(', ', array_filter(preg_split('/,\s*/', $elements), function ($v) {
        return !preg_match('/^no\b/', $v);
    }));
}
```

For example:

```
echo filter_ingredients("cheese, no tomato, no onion, mayo, no lettuce") . "\n";
echo filter_ingredients("no cheese, tomato, no onion, no mayo, lettuce") . "\n";
echo filter_ingredients("no cheese, no tomato, onion, no mayo, no lettuce") . "\n";
```

Output:

```
cheese, mayo
tomato, lettuce
onion
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/smtbt)

Note this code assumes your ingredients do not have commas in them.

Comment: This looks like what I need, but I just have the variable $elements. I tried: echo filter_ingredients($elements) . "\n";  but it doesn't work right

Comment: @EPH that is the correct way to call it. In what way does it not work right?

Comment: it leaves some of the 'no' phrases in the output : $elements are "hamburger, white bread, no peppers, no onion, no mushroom, no cheese, no bacon, no lettuce, no tomato, pickle, mayonnaise, no ketchup, no side order, no drink order"   and it outputs  "hamburger, white bread, no onion, no lettuce, no tomato, pickle, mayonnaise, no ketchup"

Comment: The $elements variable is posted to the page so I dont have access to the actual string, I was just giving an example of what the string was in the variable. Sorry, please excuse my confusion! I see it should work, I cant explain why it doesnt for me.

Comment: @EPH no worries - but if you can't give me a string which causes a problem I can't resolve the problem.

Comment: I see why some 'no' elements would get through. Some of them had a 'no&nbsp;' instead of just 'no' I removed the non breaking space and viola! works perfectly! Thank you so much Nick!

Comment: @EPH no worries - I'm glad you figured out what the issue was. You can also work around that with a slight modification to the regex in the `preg_match`, change it to `/^no\b/` (i.e. change the trailing `\s` to `\b`) and it will remove the elements with a non-breaking space following `no` as well. Note the leading `\s*` was also redundant as any leading spaces are removed by the `preg_split` (it was a hangover from when I originally wrote the code using `explode`). I've updated the answer with these changes.

Answer (score 0):

The regex probably isn't bulletproof, but this should work:

```
$pattern = '/,?\s*no \w+/';
$elements = "cheese, no tomato, no onion, mayo, no lettuce";

$str = preg_replace($pattern, '', $elements);
echo $str;


// echos "cheese, mayo"
```

By not "bulletproof", I mean for example, if your values in between the commas have commas in them, that would cause issues, etc.

Comment: Try this with `no cheese, tomato`. It leaves a hanging comma.

Comment: @Nick Yeah, def not perfect. I guess you could clean those up separately after. Or someone more regex-proficient than I might be able to fix that

Comment: @Nick Or use your answer, thats a bit more elegant ;)

Comment: You could just add a `trim`. Trying to do this with regex is tricky as you need to look ahead to the next value to decide whether to remove the trailing comma.